# docker run: make the container command use it's own environment variable instead of the host's

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, docker-run

Assuming that I set an environment variable in my `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV MY_NAME=YOYO
```

When running `docker run -it my_image bash` I am able to access `MY_NAME` like this:

```
root@dec16fb8dab1:/home $ echo $MY_NAME
YOYO
```

However, when I try `docker run my_image echo $MY_NAME`, not surprisingly I get nothing (since there is no `MY_NAME` variable on the host). How can I use docker run with a command to use the image's environement variables instead of the host's?

In a more general case, I need to see the output of `docker run my_image cmd --flag $CONTAINER_ENV_VARIABLE`.

Comment: Ask you shell to not expand `$MY_NAME` to its value, but pass it as literal argument to the command. How to do that is depend on your shell, but not docker. In `bash` single quoting should do that.

Comment: also, you can use: `docker run --env-file .env my_image` which spread environment variables and override its own

Comment: Thanks to PetSerAl's comment. `docker run my_image /bin/bash -c  'echo $MY_NAME'` solved the issue since the base image was derived from ubuntu and bash was available.